# ASP.Net Web Forms LoginStatus Multiple LoginURL - suggestions?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, webforms

I am developing a multi-lingual website. I am determining the requested language via a querystring variable eg: http://mydomain.com/default.aspx?lang=en

I am using two `<asp:LoginStatus />` controls in my masterpage. My web.config file is set up like this for forms authentication.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30" 
    name=".ASPXAUTH" path="/" requireSSL="false" 
    slidingExpiration="true" 
    defaultUrl="default.aspx" 
    cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" 
    enableCrossAppRedirects="false"/>
</authentication>
```

Currently when you click on a `<asp:LoginStatus />` you will be redirected to my login page and the url will look something like this: http://mydomain.com/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fdefault.aspx%3flang%3den

What solutions are available to me so that I can append my lang variable to my login.aspx? depending on which language is currently active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *login.aspx* code-behind can *HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode* the *ReturnUrl* variable.  Then use *HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()* to get the lang param.

Eg.

```
HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Params["ReturnUrl"]));
```

Of course in real life you'd check if that request variable even exists

[HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx)

[HttpUtility.UrlDecode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx)